# How do I use a while loop to access all the 2nd elements of lists which are the values stored in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, while-loop

If I have a dictionary like this, filled with similar lists, how can I apply a while loo tp extract a list that prints that second element:

```
racoona_valence={}
racoona_valence={"rs13283416": ["7:87345874365-839479328749+","BOBB7"],\}
```

I need to print the part that says "BOBB7" for 2nd element of the lists in a larger dictionary. There are ten key-value pairs in it, so I am starting it like so, but unsure what to do because all the examples I can find don't relate to my problem:

```
n=10
gene_list = []
while n>0:
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want a `while` loop? Would you like a `for` loop instead?

Comment: Use a list comprehension that loops over `racoona_valence.values()`

Comment: It's for a tutorial assignment on looping basics. I have to apply a while loop to go through a big dictionary like this. I've got while loop examples and for loop examples, but trying to see how to interrelate them for this task is giving me problems.

Comment: If you really have to use a `while` loop, start with `while i < len(racoona_valence):`

Comment: Ok, I'll try it like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a bunch of ways to do it depending on how well-structured your data is.

```
racoona_valence={"rs13283416": ["7:87345874365-839479328749+","BOBB7"], "rs13283414": ["7:87345874365-839479328749+","BOBB4"]}
output = []
for key in racoona_valence.keys():
    output.append(racoona_valence[key][1])
print(output)

other_output = []
for key, value in racoona_valence.items():
    other_output.append(value[1])
print(other_output)

list_comprehension = [value[1] for value in racoona_valence.values()]
print(list_comprehension)

n = len(racoona_valence.values())-1
counter = 0
gene_list = []
while counter<=n:
    gene_list.append(list(racoona_valence.values())[n][1])
    counter += 1
print(gene_list)
```

Comment: This answers my question, that final piece of code is exactly what I've been having a problem wrapping my brain around:
n = len(racoona_valence.values())-1
counter = 0
gene_list = []
while counter<=n:
    gene_list.append(list(racoona_valence.values())[n][1])
    counter += 1
print(gene_list)

Thank you very much,  I will reflect on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `list comprehension` that does what you want:

```
second_element = [x[1] for x in racoona_valence.values()]
```

Here is a `for loop` that does what you want:

```
second_element = []
for value in racoona_valence.values():
    second_element.append(value[1])
```

Here is a `while loop` that does what you want:

```
# don't use a while loop to loop over iterables, it's a bad idea
i = 0
second_element = []
dict_values = list(racoona_valence.values())
while i < len(dict_values):
    second_element.append(dict_values[i][1])
    i += 1
```

Regardless of which approach you use, you can see the results by doing the following:

```
for item in second_element:
    print(item)
```

For the example that you gave, this is the output:

```
BOBB7
```

Comment: Thank you. This works to create the final outcome. I am still learning to implement list comprehensions and while loops. If I were required to use a while loop to do the task, would the list comprehension be possible or just unnecessary?

Comment: @Psiberian_Mushky I edited my answer to be more helpful for what you are learning, have a look. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need to see to understand this better and study to try and get this!